# Connect remote systems to a Grails application using websockets? (non-http)

Tags: spring, grails, architecture, websocket

i am totally new to websockets but i am advised to use it as a technology to connect client systems to a running Grails application.

Our application clients are unable to use normal http (the websocket technology is really used a TCP channel) so a remote client system should be able to initiate a connection to our Grails app (or in-between-converter like application) and we would like to exchange data. The remote clients are no browsers so the atmosphere plugin is a no go!

Again the clients that will have to exchange data with ourGrails application are non browser systems and operate autonomous / stand alone!

The choice for Websockets is given by the facts that remote client systems will have to connect to our Grails application behind firewalls and routers. The remote client systems will initiate a connection to the running Grails server environment. (machine-to-machine communication)

Any suggestions on what i should use on the server side for software to be able to construct an environment so that remote clients can exchange data with our Grails application?

Thanks in advance!